# Get rotation of camera in Google VR

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm trying to move child of camera object smooth. To implement that, I need to know the movement of x and y axis, like Input.GetAxis in general PC platforms.

I saw the documentation and examples of Google VR, but there's not much explained well. One thing I found is GvrControllerInput.Gyro, but it's said it's deprecated and use GvrControllerInputDevice.Gyro instead, but there's no Gyro value in GvrControllerInputDevice.

Seems like basic usage is totally changed, so they are not providing static methods, and force to using internal method of the object, but couldn't find any related information about this.

So, how do I get gyro from GvrControllerInputDevice? Or is there an alternative way to make child object rotate smooth from their parent? Any advice will very appreciate it!

Comment: Since this is a VR game, presumably your player's viewpoint camera is rotating to match the display device, right? Can you simply read the transformation of the camera object in your game scene, without looking at any VR-specific API?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Gyroscope](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html) class

you can access using `Input.gyro` to get info from several different variables you may want.

you can still use `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` or "Horizontal" to get the players x and y.